# does azure guarantee two different azure app service plans (standard price tier) have two different virtual ip address?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Azure App Service Environment is not used

we have two different azure app service plans, and each app service app has one web app, but we found out that these two web apps have the same virtual ip addresses, even they are in two different app service plans, both plans use the standard price tier.

i thought each app service plan is going to use a different virtual ip address. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Azure App Service is a multi-tenant PaaS offering, this means that (potentially) there are other people using the same public IP address (because routing is happening on layer 7).

You really should not care about the IP address, you can use CNAME for DNS resolution (%app_service_name%.azurewebsites.net DNS will never change). IP address won't randomly change either, you will get an email warning you if (and when) its going to change.

Also, you observing that situation - proves what I outlined here :)